# How to display an array of objects in with typescript?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I'm very new to typescript.

I've got a wrapper component, and a bunch of child components that I want to display.

So, something like this is in my parent component html: `<component-card [someData]=someData></component-card>` works just fine and displays my component. But how do I display a list of them?

Simply doing `<li *ngFor="let card of componentCardArray"></li>` doesn't work. I tried different ways

Most tutorials just cover simple types, I searched for hours and can't find a way to do it.

Comment: Are you getting an error? and you will have to show how is your data set up

Comment: Create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) to give us some context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out! I was forgetting to put the selector after the whole *ngFor directive thing. So, here is how my components are displayed now in my wrapper.html:

```
 <div *ngFor="let card of cardArray">
      <component-card [myData]=myData></component-card>
</div>
```

Comment: <component-card *ngFor="let card of cardArray" [myData]=card.myData></component-card>

Should also be possible..